# How can I fix this array printing problem?(Java)

Tags: java, arrays

In this method I am asked to print out an Array that has 100 integers in it. It is supposed to be printed out in 10 rows of 10. However, a row will randomly break onto the next line, leaving 2 partial lines. Any clues at to what might be causing this? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: may be the myGrades doesn't contain values at some indexes..

Comment: kindly refrain on posting your code through images

Comment: @NehaK All the indexes have a number, if you count it prints it out 100 times. It just randomly cuts off parts of one line and moves it to the next.

Comment: then this is because of the space.. there is no enough window for the inputs on right side..

Comment: Does it happen more or less frequently if you change all the values to 100? Is it always the same line that breaks (line # 7)?

Comment: @JohnCorwin It does not matter what numbers they are, it breaks at different lines and at it will break at a random time in the line. Also, the System.out.println() command is not being called when it drops down (tested it with a print in there).

Answer (score 1):

You can use mod (%) operation, like below,

```
  for(int i = 0; i < myGrades.length; i++) {
      if(i % 11 == 0) {
          System.out.println("");
      } else {
          System.out.print(myGrades[i] + " ");
      }
  }
```

Comment: This still causes the issue.

Comment: Try couple of things, first expand your console view with more space. If this doesnt work, then try to display the array as-is and see if it indeed has all values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myGrades.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(myGrades[i] + " ");
    if (i % 10 == 9) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

But it looks like your code functions correctly. This is most likely an issue with console output. Also, it is conventional to start variables at 0 not 1, which would mean using `line < 10`.

Comment: This produced the same issue.

Comment: Can you possibly try a different array and see what happens?

Comment: Different array isnt working, so I am going to guess it is a problem with the console output as you said, because nothing has been working. Thanks for the help.